# Text based selection of records using CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a text field like 'address' in my Cassandra table. I want to search records on the basis of some piece of text from the 'address' field like city or street name.

for Example: I have address like 'House No. 18, Shehzad Colony, M.D.A. Chowk Lahore'. Here I want to search records having a part of string 'M.D.A. Chowk Lahore' in the address field.

how can i do this using CQL shell. can anyone guide me...

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a way to do this out-of-the-box.  In Cassandra, you need to design your tables to fit your query patterns.  So if searching for addresses by city (or whatever) is a pattern you need to support, then there are a couple of ways to do this.

You can create a new query table, and partition by `city`:

```
CREATE TABLE userAddressesByCity (
    userID uuid,
    firstName text,
    lastName text,
    street text,
    city text,
    province text,
    postalCode text,
    PRIMARY KEY (city,userID));
```

This table structure would support querying by `city` as a partition key, and it also has `userID` as a clustering key to ensure uniqueness.

If you're working with addresses, a useful technique is to create a [User Defined Type](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html) (UDT).  UDTs are useful if you want to store a user's address in a single column.  But you would still want to create a table specifically-designed to serve a query by whichever column you require.

Note: You *could* try one table and create a secondary index on one of the columns, but secondary indexes perform poorly at-scale, so I don't recommend that.